# Open SQL statement with a subtraction in WHERE condition

Tags: abap, opensql

```
SELECT * FROM dbtab
WHERE a - b GE c.
```

The problem is in ABAP with the `a - b` part. Is there a way to make such a WHERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, that's not possible with [Open SQL](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/ABENWHERE_LOGEXP_COMPARE.htm). And btw, you don't select **from** an internal table (but usually into it).

Comment: It was a dbtab. I was in a rush. Thank you!

Comment: @vwegert An example in the link you provide disagrees:  http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abensql_expr_in_where_cond_abexa.htm (It really is an ABAP 7.50 feature, in the 7.40 system I have access to the example fails the syntax check)